# Set up a  GUI managed firewall for other machines?

Tags: firewall

What ways are there of setting up a firewall that can be managed with a GUI that allows you to firewall (filter*) incoming traffic routed to other machines?
Can GUFW do it? FireStarter? (or should that be avoided because it is supposedly no longer updated?)

*By filtering, I'm mean the traffic I am setting rules up for is not destined for this computer. It is either from or to other computers on my LAN.

Say, for (a simplified, hypothetical) example:

> I have an ethernet connection from my ISP that I have plugged into eth0. It gets an address of 216.228.1.189 and I also have 216.228.15.0/24 routed to me, so I don't have to do any NAT. I have a switch attached to my second ethernet port (eth1). Attached to it are various PCs (that do not necessarily have a host-based firewall on them) that have addresses out of my 216.228.15.0/24 block statically set. How can I use my Ubuntu box (which is doing routing and no NAT) to block incoming connections from eth0 that are being routed to my various PCs and let through just a few specific ports on a per host basis?

[image: Example network layout]

Comment: I'm drawing a blank trying to understand the question - can you add to your question an example of what you are trying to achieve? - especially what you mean be "stateful forwarding firewall"

Comment: @fossfreedom By forwarding, I'm talking about the case where the computer is routing traffic for other computers. Maybe filtering would be a better word? I would like to be able to, for example, block traffic through the computer that is headed for other computers.

Comment: Gufw is updated actually (even in 12.04), and it might be able to do the job, but your question seems abandoned as @jrg said.

Comment: @fossfreedom I did lots of editing, is it more understandable now?

Comment: @Azendale - actually yes - more understandable.  Remember to keep an eye on the question and edit it every so often to bump it to the top of the active list.  As an alternative, a small bounty might give more encouragement to someone out there who has a speciality/knowledge in this area.  Good luck and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in checking out:

[zentyal](http://www.zentyal.com/)

From their webpage:

> Manage all your computer network services through one single platform. Zentyal is a Network Gateway, Unified Threat Manager, Office Server, Infrastructure Manager, Unified Communications Server or a combination of them. All services based on the same technology and fully integrated. For the first time you can make your network act as one single unit.

Any of the ones listed here should work as well:
[Wikipedia list of router or firewall distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_router_or_firewall_distributions)

Comment: I agree, I think you are better off using any of the firewall specific distributions over UFW. Many come with web interfaces, from ipcop to smoothwall.